# Executing powershell command for getting megaraid status and sending output to mail using task scheduler in windows2012

Tags: windows, powershell

I have windows 2012 server with LSI Megaraid controller. I am able to get raid status using below command in powershell and redirect output to a file.

```
C:\> MegaCli64.exe -LDInfo -Lall -aALL | Out-File raid.txt
```

However I tried to run same command using task scheduler and it is not working. I want to send the output of raid command or send raid.txt to a mail using task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some piece of advise for sceduled jobs :

1) Always set the working directory if you work with local files.

2) Always use the full path (not the relative one) for the programs you call and the files you manipulate. Do not expect the exe you call being in the paths pointed by `$env:path`.

3) Put your commands into a script file and make sure that a log (any type), with a time stamp, is composed each time your script is called.

4) Here is one way, but it exits multiples ways, to register your script in the scheduler :

```
# First set a Trigger
$SixInTheMorning = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "06:00 AM"
# Second set your script
$scriptPath1 = 'C:\Batchs\WS_PowerShell\Myscript.PS1'
# Third register you job
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "AJobName" -FilePath $scriptPath1 -Trigger $scriptPath1
```

Comment: Thanks JP for your suggestion. As you said I was using relative path and hence it was not working. I used full path and it worked.